# Count b or B in even lines

Tags: awk

I need count the number of times in the even lines of the file.txt the letter 'b' or 'B' appears, e.g. for the file.txt like:

```
everyB or gbnBra
uitiakB and kanapB bodddB
Kanbalis astroBominus
```

I got the first part but I need to count these b or B letters and I do not know how to count them together

```
awk '!(NR%2)' file.txt
```

Comment: what's the expected output? simple way of counting letters in a line: `tr -cd 'bB' | wc -c`; also see this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396586/234539) which you should be able to tweak for your case

Answer (score 6):

```
$ awk '!(NR%2){print gsub(/[bB]/,"")}' file
4
```

Comment: Of course! The `gsub` function returns the number of substitutions made. Nicely thought!

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, one more approach with `awk` written on mobile will try it in few mins should work but.

```
awk -F'[bB]' 'NR%2 == 0{print (NF ? NF - 1 : 0)}' Input_file
```

Thanks to @Ed sir for solving zero matches found line problem in comments.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
awk '!(NR%2)' file.txt | tr -cd 'Bb' | wc -c
```

**Explanation:**

- `awk '!(NR%2)' file.txt` : keep only even lines from file.txt
- `tr -cd 'Bb'` : keep only B and b characters
- `wc -c` : count characters

**Example:**

With file bellow, the result is 4.

```
everyB or gbnBra
uitiakB and kanapB bodddB
Kanbalis astroBominus
```

Answer (score 3):

In a single awk:

```
awk '!(NR%2){gsub(/[^Bb]/,"");print length}' file.txt
```

`gsub(/[^Bb]/,"")` deletes every character in the line the line except for B and b.

`print length` prints the length of the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
$ sed -n '2~2s/[^bB]//gp' file | wc -c
```

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that *first~step* is a GNU extension.